# What is reason for "failed to connect to server" in Thunderbird?

Tags: 16.04, thunderbird

Using Ubuntu 64 bit 16.04 with Thunderbird 52.6.0, I get "failed to connect to server" in Thunderbird. I'm only using 1 email a/c which is gmail. What's the reason? BTW internet browsing using Chrome is Ok including looking at gmail's emails. Firewall is off.

Comment: What are the security setup used in gmail, `two step` `app specific password`, etc!

Comment: I forgot to say that this is a new computer. Also, T'bird was Ok yesterday.

Comment: Also, another computer can still access email using T'bird. So my conclusion is that a setting has been changed in T'bird just on this new computer.

Comment: T'bird uses OAuth2 with password input yesterday. Can I force input of the password again?

Comment: Yes try password input again!

Comment: How do I force password input as T'bird does not ask me for the password?

Comment: Using Edit->Preferences followed by selecting Security tab and then Saved Passwords, shows that there are no saved passwords. On another computer there are 7 saved passwords for gmail a/c etc. So how do I get these passwords back into T'bird?

Answer (score 0):

I've realised what caused the problem. I ticked the Checkbox for Master Password when I first entered the email (for gmail) password and entered a Master Password. So it worked on that instance of Thunderbird but failed when I closed T'bird and started it again (e.g. after rebooting). What is then supposed to happen is that T'bird should ask me for the Master Password on starting but it never did: I assume that that is a bug in T'bird. So I quit T'bird and deleted the .thunderbird directory and started T'bird again which then asked me for the email password and I did NOT tick the Master Password checkbox. T'bird then downloaded my email folders. I then quit T'bird and started it again after a reboot and everything was Ok.